# android sqlite database disk image is malformed

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have a problem with my database in android app.

I'm copying the database from the assets folder to the datbase path
after that, some queries work just find & other queries return :

database disk image is malformed.
but when I check those tables using sqlbrowser, it works just fine.
Note : all the queries are select statements only.

Comment: android sqlite databases requires a few specificities. see http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/

Comment: I followed that tutorial exactly

Comment: Is your database bigger than 1Mb?

Comment: Yes, but I guess the 1MB issue is only on emulators

Comment: I recommend that you switch to using `SQLiteAssetHelper` instead of that tutorial: https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper

Comment: Bingo, it worked
the problem was the database was corrupted in some parts cuz someone opened it with a text editor.